# How to suspend Thread using java.util.concurrent?

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

I have looked everywhere. How to suspend/pause it by code until I call it to awake using any `java.util.concurrent`methods/objects? I have simple Thread with run method:

When I press button it stops then starts but the problem is that I get exception when I start it again. I want it play/pause like in the media player.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
```

### Full working code(with exceptions):

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Window extends JFrame {
    ThreadPanel leftPanel, rightPanel;
    Thread leftThread, rightThread;

    public Window() {
        super("StopResume");
    }

    public void createGUI() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout());
        add(leftPanel = new ThreadPanel());
        add(rightPanel = new ThreadPanel());
        leftThread = new Thread(leftPanel);
        rightThread = new Thread(rightPanel);
        leftThread.start();
        rightThread.start();
        setSize(800, 600);
        setVisible(true);
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                int confirmed = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Zamknąć", "Potwierdzenie", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
                if (confirmed == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
                    dispose();//tu podmienic kod
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Window().createGUI();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

---

```
 import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class ThreadPanel extends JPanel implements Runnable {
    public static final String SUSPENDED = "GO", RUNNING = "SUSPEND";
    JTextArea txt;
    JButton ppButton;
    DateFormat dateFormat;
    Lock lock;
    Condition cond;
    boolean running;

    public ThreadPanel() {
        super();
        createGUI();
        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        lock = new ReentrantLock();
        cond = lock.newCondition();
        running = true;
    }

    public void createGUI() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(txt = new JTextArea(), JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        add(jsp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(ppButton = new JButton(RUNNING), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        ppButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                System.out.println(1);
                if (running) {
                    running = false;
                    ppButton.setText(SUSPENDED);
                } else {
                    running = true;
                    ppButton.setText(RUNNING);
                    lock.unlock();
                }
                lock.lock();
                if (!running) {
                    cond.signalAll();
                }

                lock.unlock();

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            lock.lock();
            try {
                if (!running)
                    cond.await();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            txt.append("\n" + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
            try {
                Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random() * 1001 + 500));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(2);
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: change true to false to terminate

Comment: @sanket: That won't suspend it. It'll terminate it.

Comment: Why not use wait()/notify()? Why do you depend on java.util.concurrent?

Comment: There is no suspend/resume. Use synchronization constructs like Semaphore, CountDownLatch, ReentrantLock and friends.

Comment: @p000ison Because wait/notify is a legacy mechanism, advised against for any new code.

Comment: @p000ison wait/notify is in most cases a bad idea. It hides the connection between the peers and you'll usually end up with a thread locked in a wait and you have no idea who is supposed to send the notify to it.

Comment: @yoda You have pasted some code. It appears that it could work. Since you have not indicated any complaint with it, it would seem you already have a working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you want a button to start and stop the thread. So basically you need to in the `actionPerformed()`, acquire the lock, look up the state of things, manipulate the state, tell the waiting entity that something changed, and then release all your locks.

The `Runnable` thread (for lack of a label) should remain mostly unchanged but should check the `Condition` within a loop to avoid the case where your `signalAll()` wakes and the `Condition` still is not symenticly true or false. (`signal()` and `signalAll()` are not guaranteed to be sync right after the lock is released, so 2 calls to `actionPerformed()` may have happened already).

```
    public void createGUI() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(txt = new JTextArea(), JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        add(jsp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(ppButton = new JButton(RUNNING), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        ppButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                // This is where we acquire the lock to safely look at the state
                lock.lock();
                System.out.println(1);
                // Manipulate the state
                if (running) {
                    running = false;
                    ppButton.setText(SUSPENDED);
                } else {
                    running = true;
                    ppButton.setText(RUNNING);
                }

                // Signal that this conditional changed (is either true or false now)
                cond.signalAll();
                // Release the lock so other entities can go forward
                lock.unlock();

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            lock.lock();
            try {
                // This should block until this condition is true with a loop
                while (!running)
                    cond.await();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            txt.append("\n" + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
            // No need to sleep()
            System.out.println(2);
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Depends on luck it freezes sometimes for 20 seconds. But sometimes works fast.

Comment: Hmm it's possible this is the event thread. But that lock acquisition should be pretty fast unless the calendar is updating at the time you are pressing the button

Comment: Oh you have a sleep in there, that is why :)

Comment: The thread is holding the lock that entire time so you won't be able to handle a button press during that time. I don't know why the sleep was there in the first place, so I left it, but I suggest removing it entirely

Comment: I pot sleep so it will print in area data only every 500-1500ms not at the speed of light.

Comment: Well the sleep should then be done outside the lock if you still want it. Since you are basically blocking all render events

Answer (score 1):

One way to do what I think you're asking for is to use a CyclicBarrier (from java.util.concurrent), parameterising it with two "parties".

The first thread to call `await` on the barrier will be suspended/blocked until a second thread also calls `await`, at which point both threads can proceed.

Here's a simple code sample:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // a barrier requiring two threads to call await before
        // any thread can proceed past the barrier
        final CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(2);

        new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // do some stuff
                    System.out.println("in thread, before the barrier");

                    // calling await blocks until two threads
                    // (this one and one other) have called await
                    barrier.await();

                    // do some more stuff
                    System.out.println("in thread, after the barrier");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();

        try {
            System.out.println("main thread, before barrier");

            // calling await blocks until two threads
            // (this one and one other) have called await
            barrier.await();

            System.out.println("main thread, after barrier");
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you only have one thread and then you suspend it, nothing will happen in your application - it will be hung forever.

Comment: You have 2 implicitly. Your JPanel as a Runnable should live inside another thread, outside your main and swing threads. But whichever entity actually starts the thread should be the one triggering the "wake" event of the Runnable, maybe you should add the thread creation starting code to your question for better clarity

Comment: @GregGiacovelli  Now I posted full working code. But it throws exceptions.

Comment: Ah so the click event, is a separate event thread. You have to call lock from within it in order for that code to work, right now it is only calling unlock, but the thread never acquired it. That's why you get the IllegalMonitor since you are essentially trying to release an entry that you never had (At least at first glance this seems to be the case)

Comment: Using @Stevie's code here instead of the lock and conditions, would get you what you want though. There are your two threads (The Runnable, and the Swing Event Thread).

Comment: @GregGiacovelli When there is no `unlock`(this one which causes the exception) the thread never awakes.

Comment: no I am not saying remove entirely unlock, I am saying that in that thread context, it never acquired a lock to be able to safely call unlock in the first place (inside the actionPerformed() method). So if you call unlock, it has to be balanced by a previous call to lock in the same thread otherwise it's a weird state to be in and causes an Exception

Comment: "I just have one Thread"---and what is this, then? `leftThread = new Thread(leftPanel);
        rightThread = new Thread(rightPanel);
        leftThread.start();
        rightThread.start();`

Comment: These threads have nothing to do with each other, we can delete one of them.

Comment: It's also a very bad idea to block the Event Thread, just an FYI. You might end up with UI lag or starvation since the render queue might not be able to be purged while it's reaping thread is blocked

Comment: @Stevie Why do I get main thread, before barrier
in thread, before the barrier
in thread, after the barrier
main thread, after barrier

Comment: @Stevie Insteead before barrier in thread, main thread In the result of your code.

Comment: EAch of those threads has a separate lock, but if you hve them each have a separete cyclic barrier as @Stevie suggests, I believe your code should work and since the thread is started because an action can be performed it should be safe

Comment: @Yoda you mean the order? because there's no guarantee about the order of execution between the threads - that's part of the fun of concurrency.

Comment: @Stevie you made me cry ; /

Comment: You have *three* threads total. Deleting one of those brings the count down to two. Stevie, in his answer, is referring to those two threads as the "first thread" and the "second thread".

Comment: Oh now I see what you are trying to do, You might just have to put the lock.lock() at the start of your performAction() and lock.unlock() at the end of the method and that should solve your problem. the call to lock.unlock() in the state where it sets running = true might just need to invoke the condition.signal() instead. As it is right now, nothing would "wake" up the blocked conditional wait in the Runnanle Thread

Comment: @Yoda I highly recommend Brian Goetz' book, "Java Concurrency in Practice" - it will make you happy again.

Comment: @GregGiacovelli Could you please show me how to correct this code so the thread will wake up and go without exception.

Comment: @Yoda My answer was in response to a very different version of the question - you've moved the goal-posts considerably during the course of these comments and the edits to the question. You are probably better off pursuing your use of locks instead, but I think you're on dangerous ground without preparing yourself with a good background on threading (e.g. Brian Goetz' book)

Comment: @stevie I don't think the `CyclicBarrier` is appropriate here because it will make the "notifying" thread block until the "waiting" thread arrives at the junction.

Comment: @Marko I agree - the question changed since I answered, and I don't think my answer is appropriate to the question any more.

Comment: @Yoda, I added my answer, I misunderstood the question as well previously